# numpy from pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame convert to string array

Tags: arrays, pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a requirement to query a column in a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.  I wish to create a string array from that column.  I am using numpty arrays to achieve this however the result I get is an array of arrays

```
import numpy as np
df = spark.read.load(parquetfiles/part-00000-e7dad738-8895-45e8-9926-39c9d677b999-c000.snappy.parquet', format='parquet')

    data_array = np.asarray(df.select('name').collect())
    print(type(data_array),data_array)
    
    for x in data_array:
        str = x[0]
        print(type(x))
```

The output I get from my first print is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [['London']
 ['New York']
 ['Paris']
 ['Rome']
 ['Berlin']]
```

And from the second Print I get

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So my question: is it possible to get these values as string array or failing that can I create a dynamic which I add the values of str in my for loop to as strings?

Things I've tried.

- use asarray instead of array, as you can see I get the same.
- data_array = list(data_array), well I get a list but its not usable as it contains all the meta too.

Open to suggestions and additional reading rather than full solutions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power of the post.

```
import numpy as np
df = spark.read.load('parquetfiles/part-00000-e7dad738-8895-45e8-9926-39c9d677b999-c000.snappy.parquet', format='parquet')

data_array = np.asarray(df.select('name').collect())
cases = []    
    
for x in data_array:
   str = x[0]
   cases.append(str)
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.